# Plotting a violin plot with lists

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I would like to plot a violin plot using Python for a multivariate regression problem. I attempt to obtain a prediction scalar value for time series input. The libraries of choice are probably matplotlib and / or seaborn but I'm open to alternative suggestions well.

This is what I have:

1. A list [g_1,g_2,...g_n] of n ground truth values for each of my n subjects.
2. k time series inputs (i.e. lists) consisting of j elements for each of my n subjects. Please note that k and j don't have to be equal for each subject.
3. k predictions for each of my n subjects.

Example input:

- Ground truth: [14,67,342,5]
- Time series input: [[19,2434,23432,-123,-54],[99,23,4,-6],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[-1,-2,-3]]

Example output after performing a regression:

- Predictions: [17,54,312,-2]

What I would like to obtain is a nice violin plot as shown in [this tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/violin-plot-for-data-analysis/). This is how my pandas data frame looks like:

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(
{'Predictions': predictions, # This is a list of k elements 
 'Subject IDs': subjectIDs, # This is a list of n strings
 'Ground truths': groundtruths #  This is a list of n float values
})
```

Attempting to draw a plot with

```
sns.violinplot( ax = ax, y = dataframe["Predictions"] )
```

only results in:

> TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc add

Additionally, I also already tried to follow the official [seaborn documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html#seaborn.violinplot), using the command

```
ax = sns.violinplot(x="Subject IDs", y="Predictions", data=dataframe)
```

instead. However, this only results in

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

---

Update: If I treat the "Predictions" list as a tuple, I manage to create a plot without errors but unfortunately it's completely messed up as it puts all prediction values on the y-axis (see below for a snippet).

[image: Messed up violin plot]

---

Thus, my question is: How can I draw a plot with all subject IDs on the x-axis, the ground truths on the y-axis and the probability distribution of my predictions, the corresponding mean values and a confidence interval as violin plot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I solved my problem. The problem was with my input pandas dataframe. I had to make sure that each of my observation was assigned exactly one single prediction and **not** a complete list.

This is what my data frame should have looked like:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(
{'groundtruths': groundtruthsList,
 'predictions': predictionsList,
 'subjectIDs': subjectIDsList
})
print(data.head())

   groundtruths    predictions    subjectIDs  
 0    70            75.864983        01  
 1    70            50.814903        01  
 2    70            80.715569        01  
 3    70            70.627260        01  
 4    70            49.516285        01
 .    .                 .             .
 .    .                 .             .
 .    .                 .             .
```

Now, as the data frame has the right format, I can easily draw nice violin plots with

```
sns.violinplot(x="subjectIDs", y="predictions", data=data)
```

A simple [seaborn scatterplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html) can be used to nicely put the ground truth for each subject in this plot as well.